# No suitable method found for divide

Tags: java

I checked the other "no suitable method found" threads, but none of them are for divide, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

I'm retrieving text the user entered (LoanAmount) and using it to display monthly payments.

I'm trying to display monthly payments for a mortgage with a 10-year term. I'm using the formula LoanAmount + (LoanAmount * InterestRate) / 120. I realize that interest calculations are more complicated than that, but for this example the interest doesn't compound.

I've tried casting LoanAmount.

```
BigDecimal purchasePrice = new BigDecimal(purchasePriceTextField.getText());
            BigDecimal downPayment = new BigDecimal(downPaymentTextField.getText());
            BigDecimal loanAmount = purchasePrice.subtract(downPayment);
            BigDecimal interestRate = new BigDecimal(interestRateTextField.getText());


            loanAmountTextField.setText(currency.format(loanAmount));
            BigDecimal temp = loanAmount + loanAmount.multiply(interestRate);
            tenYearTextField.setText(currency.format(temp.divide(120, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
```

The exact error is

```
MortgageCalculatorController.java:69: no suitable method found for divide(int, int, RoundingMode)
tenYearTextField.setText(currency.format(temp.divide(120, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs and figure out which of the available methods you want to use. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: Take another look at the javadoc.  Notice how all of the divide methods expect a `BigDecimal` divisor, not an `int`.

Comment: Now I see. I thought when the compiler said (int, int, RoundingMode) it meant I **needed** two ints and a RoundingMode. I gather that instead the error means that the compiler found no constructor with the supplied arguments -- is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The Error indicates that there is no method divide with params *int, int, RoundingMode* in BigDecimal.

The Method you probably want to use is

`public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`

So you should probably change your line 69 to
`tenYearTextField.setText(currency.format(temp.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(120), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));`

You may also get an error in Line 68, this will fix it:

`BigDecimal temp = loanAmount.add(loanAmount.multiply(interestRate));`